# How can I pass a excel/csv file as a function parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, function, file-io, parameter-passing

How can I pass a excel/csv file as a function parameter?
I have wrote a piece of code to copy content from one excel file to another excel file. Now I want to define it as a function so I just have to mention file name from which I want to transfer data to my existing file.
Thanks a lot in advance.
I am very new to Python Programming, and looking forward to learn a lot.

def feed_input_file(InputFile):

```
   InputFile = "D:\\Python_Projects\\ABC.xlsx"  #(I am passing Input file at the moment but I don't wanna pass it here)
```

#( Here I am trying to call my function parameter value)

Workbook1 = xl.load_workbook(feed_input_file(InputFile))

............

Comment: What do you want to define as a function?  The copy or the write?  Please show some effort

Comment: Hi itprorh66, sure, I am defining my function somewhat like: 

##############
def feed_input_file(InputFile):

 
    InputFile = "D:\\Python_Projects\\ABC.xlsx"


    #( Here I am trying to call my function parameter value)
    Workbook1 = xl.load_workbook(feed_input_file(InputFile))

##################
The problem is in second line I don't know how to make my argument arbitrary instead of hardcoding the input file ABC.xlsx Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you edit your Question to show the code using the code markup?  It is impossible to understand as currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not quite sure what you are trying to do but if you want to create a function that will take a filename as an argument you could try something along the lines of:

```
def processFile(fn:str):
    #Reads in the contents of file specified by fn
    content = ''
    with open(fn, 'a') as f:
        data = f.read()
        #Do something with data here to create content
    return content
```

Then in your main part of the script

```
for filename in listofFiles:
    fle_out = processFile(filename
    #Do something here with file contents
```

Comment: Thanks a lot itprorh66. It worked for me.

Comment: If this solves your problem please mark the problem answered